# Make my own error for serde_json Deserialize

Tags: rust

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON file with a pre-existing format into my own, in Rust, using serde_json.

I'd like to do this by implementing a deserializer for the class.

My problem is that the JSON file could be malformed in such a way that `raw_json_result` could still decode just fine, but the resulting data structure would be itself malformed.  In this case, I want to return an error.

What's the mechanism for forming a valid error object here?  I'm thinking I want an `Err(something_valid)` line -- I just don't know how to make the `something_valid`.

```rust
impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for MyClass {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let raw_json_result = MyAliasedClassFromJson::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        MyClass::from_cal_json::<D>(cal_json)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of [`de::Error`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/trait.Error.html). You probably want to use `custom` or `invalid_valid`.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you have some `MyError` type, which implements [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html), [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html), and [`Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html). Then if you try to return `Err(MyError::SomethingBadHappened)` then the most straightforward way to get it working is to simply add [`.map_err(D::Error::custom)`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/trait.Error.html#tymethod.custom).

```rust
Err(MyError::SomethingBadHappened).map_err(D::Error::custom)
```

---

Here's a short example:

```rust
use std::error;
use std::fmt;

// serde = "1.0"
use serde::de::Error;
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};

#[derive(Debug)]
enum MyError {
    YouAreNotBob,
    // ...
}

impl error::Error for MyError {}

impl fmt::Display for MyError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        use MyError::*;
        match self {
            YouAreNotBob => write!(f, "YouAreNotBob"),
            // ...
        }
    }
}

pub fn deserialize_bob<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<String, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let string = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;

    if string == "bob" {
        Ok(string)
    } else {
        Err(MyError::YouAreNotBob).map_err(D::Error::custom)
    }
}
```

Comment: Heh.  When I'm doing throwaway code the first variable gets named "bob".

Comment: Perfect!  I just tested my version of this, and it worked.  The serde_json documentation has the line about using `map_err`, but without the surrounding context that you supplied, I couldn't make sense of it.

Comment: I just provided a simple and general example, sorry for the confusion. But great that you figured it out :)

Comment: Unless you wrote the serde_json documentation, you have nothing to apologize for (and if you did -- feel free to paste your answer her into there).

Comment: Don't forget to put the trait in scope, or use the full-qualified path: `map_err(serde::de::Error::custom)`